# "Cardboard" doesn't show up as an option in Unity Android options after installing Google Cardboard Unity SDK

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

For some reason, after installing the Google Cardboard SDK unitypackage in Unity, I still can't see "Cardboard" as an option in Unity's Android build options. Here's a screenshot of Google telling you the options that should be there:

[google cardboard sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocjaP.png)

And here is what I see:

[my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnVvS.png)

Is there a step I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File > Build Settings.

Select Android from the platform list.

Click on the player setting. You should be able to see and cardboard option now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature and not a bug.

If you install any of the most used VR SDK such as Google Cardboard SDK or Oculus SDK, Unity will automatically disable its built-in Native VR system and utilize that installed SDK.

By doing this, it will avoid conflicts of having a VR script running on top of another VR script.

Comment: What do I select in that box? I still see "Must add at least one virtual reality SDK."

Comment: Select "None" That's it.